# Error:- Cannot index into a null array while installing java

Tags: java, powershell, packer

I am trying to install java using powershell Invoke-WebRequest command on packer instance however, I am getting below error;

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:94
+ ... content | %{[regex]::matches($_, '(?:<a title="Download Java software ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Command;

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12"`

`$URL = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).Content | %{[regex]::matches($_, '(?:<a title="Download Java software for Windows .64-bit." href=")(.*)(?:">)').Groups[1].Value}`

`Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -OutFile jre8.exe $URL`

`Start-Process .\jre8.exe '/s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0' -wait`

Few weeks ago I was able to run it successfully but since yesterday getting the above error.
Any advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This happens, as there is no such as string as `Download Java software for Windows` on the web page. Since the regex doesn't match anything, `Groups` member doesn't exist and you'll get an error about trying to index into a non-existing member.

Either use a web browser's View Source command, or save the content on a text file and view it with Notepad like so,

```
$cc = (Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).Content
Set-Content -Path c:\temp\javapage.txt -Value $cc
notepad c:\temp\javapage.txt
```

The page loads a bunch of Javascript that generates the actual page seen on a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes I could see "title" string has been removed from web page so, in this case what should be the correct URL so that it will install java?

Comment: @SagarJadhav That would be a topic for different a question. Maybe something like "How do I download latest Java with a script?" and explain that the direct download link doesn't exist anymore. Maybe Oracle offers a solution already.